# How to open Soap Web Service WSDL in SoapUI in Kerberos enabled system?

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, kerberos

I have a scenario in which *I need to send a soap request using SoapUI and get the response, in a Kerberized environment.*

The Web Service is hosted on a **Kerberos** system.
**I am able to get the WSDL content on IE browser**, its working. But not through **SoapUI**.

I have followed: [SoapUI: SPNEGO/Kerberos Authentication](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/spnego/kerberos-authentication.html)

But I am not able to fetch the WSDL itself. It asks for windows NT authentication. (userName, Password, and Domain)

I have tried all the possible combinations. But was not able to get the solution. :(

I see the following error all the time:
*"Error loading [<>]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error:"*

I wonder if someone can give me some idea or experience to solve the issue.

My environment: 
I am on SoapUI free version (5.3.0) running in a Windows Kerberized VM.
And have added the options specified in the link provided above, to .vmoption as well as the soupui.bat file [(as specified here)](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Where-are-log-files-stored-on-SoapUI/td-p/30302).

Please help me if you have any idea...
***Thanks.***